# What is the meaning of `df[df['factor']]` syntax in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading some Pandas code where they have this bit of code

`df_new = df[df['factor']]`

I understand that `df['factor']` gets the column called factor from `df`. But what does the second `df` do?

Comment: It selects the rows for which 'factor' is True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed your have df like below

```
df
  factor  a  b  c  d
0      a  1  1  1  1
1      b  1  1  1  1
2      c  1  1  1  1

df[df['factor']] #select the column which contain in the factor columns
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1
```

If your factor is `True` and `False`

```
df[df['factor']]
   factor  a  b  c  d
0    True  1  1  1  1


#   factor  a  b  c  d
#0    True  1  1  1  1
#1   False  1  1  1  1
#2   False  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: So it's basically a way to select multiple columns based on the names in one column?

Answer (score 0):

The second `df` in `df[df['factor']]` refers to the `DataFrame` on which the boolean indexing is being performed.

The boolean indexing operation `[df['factor']]` creates a boolean mask that is a Series of `True` and `False` values with the same length as the `DataFrame`. This boolean mask is used to select only those rows from the `DataFrame df` where the value in the `df['factor']` column is `True`.

So the whole expression `df[df['factor']]` selects only the rows from the `DataFrame df`, where the value in the `df['factor']` column is `True`, and returns a new `DataFrame` with only those rows. This new `DataFrame` is then assigned to `df_new`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The second df, i.e. the `df['factor']` inside `df[]`, is the condition term, so `df[df['factor']]` will select the rows where the value of `df['factor']` is True.

Tips: The values of the `factor` column must be boolean(True/ False), or you will get an error. If the column value is number or string, we can use expression like `df[df['number'] > 3]`, or `df[df['words'] == 'python']` .